# How to execute installed clickonce application programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, process, clickonce

I have a windows application which is published through ClickOnce. I have .exe and .application files with Application Files folder as well.
The installation of my application is successful and I have .appref-ms file in my desktop as well which lunch application successfully.

Now I want to run this installed application through my C# code or JavaScript code. I achieved this by c# code through 
Process.Start(appPath, argsToPass); 
But this work only my web application is running on IIS Express mode. When I switch my application on Local IIS and create virtual directory, then Process.Start(appPath, argsToPass) does not start my application.

```
public void lunchClickOnce()
{
    string applicationReferencePath = @"C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\myDesktopApp.appref-ms";
    //If application is not Installed/found
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(applicationReferencePath))
    {
        string url = "http://myweb.com/ClickOnce/myDesktopApp.application";
        byte[] applicationManifest = null;
        string applicationReference = null;

        // Download the application manifest.
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            applicationManifest = wc.DownloadData(url);
        }

        // Build the .appref-ms contents.
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(applicationManifest))
        {
            XNamespace asmv1 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";
            XNamespace asmv2 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            XElement assembly = doc.Element(asmv1 + "assembly");
            XElement identity = assembly.Element(asmv1 + "assemblyIdentity");
            XElement deployment = assembly.Element(asmv2 + "deployment");
            XElement provider = deployment.Element(asmv2 + "deploymentProvider");
            XAttribute codebase = provider.Attribute("codebase");
            XAttribute name = identity.Attribute("name");
            XAttribute language = identity.Attribute("language");
            XAttribute publicKeyToken = identity.Attribute("publicKeyToken");
            XAttribute architecture = identity.Attribute("processorArchitecture");

            applicationReference = String.Format(
                "{0}#{1}, Culture={2}, PublicKeyToken={3}, processorArchitecture={4}",
                codebase.Value,
                name.Value,
                language.Value,
                publicKeyToken.Value,
                architecture.Value);
        }

        // Write the .appref-ms file (ensure that it's Unicode encoded).
        using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(applicationReferencePath))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                writer.Write(applicationReference);
            }
        }
    }
    string argsToPass = "ArgsToSend";
    //Start/Install the application
    Process.Start(applicationReferencePath, argsToPass);
}
```

Expected output is that my code successfully run/launch clickonce installed application.

Comment: Not real sure if this will help you, but when you build you will set the URL or path that the ClickOnce app will check for updates when it launches.  Not real clear on what you are trying to do though.  Are you branching the app?

Comment: I want to download ClickOnce application from server and install to Client machine silently.

Comment: I believe the end-user will need to run the setup file.

Comment: ok end-user done once time (Installation). after this can I open this installed application through code. Just like Zoom call desktop application open automatically on call connect(through code).

Comment: I'm not sure.  Seems like IIS wouldn't have access to folders outside of inetpub... and definitely wouldn't have access to the client's folders.  Seems like you'd want an ActiveX control instead.

Comment: Yes you are right but ActiveX controls are only IE depended and also I have no option to setup any type of configurations/settings to client machine.

Comment: I just have a question. In zoom call connectivity how zoom knows that client machine have installed his desktop plugin and how that application trigger automatically.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zoom calls... but I'm guessing this is a client side app.